# Compare first three parts of an IP address only for duplicate

Tags: php

I am managing a website in PHP that gives a reward out to visitors. There is already a limit of one IP address per 24 hours but we need to extend this limit to one IP per range an hour. Currently we can see up to thirty IP addresses in the same range claiming the reward.

I have a database result of IP addresses seen in the last hour and I have the users current IP address.

I am wondering if someone knows a good function to use or has their own to compare if the users current IP belongs to a network seen in the last hour. From the same IP address below we would want to compare and return true if 1, 2 and 3 have a match.

Example IP
1.2.3.4 (Match on 1, 2 and 3 would return true. Full match is already checked for.)

If we get a match then no reward is paid and the user has to return later. I assume that network admins are taking advantage of their resources to harvest the rewards from our site which is unfair to others who would want to take part.

Comment: I'm able to obtain a new IP every minute by unplugging the AC cable of my router. -> forget about your IP restriction, use user authentication

Comment: Does your database store IP addresses as strings or 32-bit integers?

Comment: Also, the same IP address could be used by different visitors, and all of them should be entitled to claim the price. Focus on the user instead of the IP address.

Comment: @DCoder I have never obtained an IP out of the same C class subnet after reconnection before. This sounds more unlikely than likely for me

Comment: If two different visitors use the same subnet then you are penalizing someone who shouldn't be. If Bob is in Miami with ISP ComCants with IP 78.33.12.221 and Alice is also a ComCants subscriber with IP 78.33.12.69 then what? Trying to ban someone by IP is fruitless and ultimately will not be a good solution.

Comment: I probably have the IP address of the bloke across the road. Should we be considered the same person despite he is a ....?

Comment: Oh boy. Opinions is not was I was looking for. There are admins using ranges of 100 addresses to harvest the site which we are trying to stop. We have not seen any other duplicates like this within an hour. So no one knows how to compare the first three parts of an IP in PHP? That's weird as it seemed like a simple enough question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, since everyone was too busy saying how stupid a thing this is to do rather than answer the question I'll answer it myself. Just assume that we have valid reasons for doing this rather than me taking the time to explain our reasons!

I took the local IP address and turned it into an array using the explode function.

```
$ipArray = explode(".", $ip, 4);
```

Then I removed the last entry.

```
array_pop($ipArray);
```

I then iterated through the external IP addresses if any and did the same to each of them.

```
$exArray = explode(".", $exIP, 4);
array_pop($exArray);
```

Lastly all I needed to do was compare the two arrays.

```
if ($ipArray == $exArray) { return true; }
```

Perhaps there is an easier way to do this but this has worked well for us. We have lost the rewards held on our site to just a very few network admins who have used their resources to strip our site. Unplugging and plugging back in your router for a new IP is nothing compared to people taking 200 rewards in just a few seconds.

Here is the full code used.
https://github.com/Bushstar/applebyte-faucet/commit/643bcd2111378bd6d1b2da34357290bd1d4136ae

Comment: `Valid Reason : Reputation +15`